# Binding does not work with StackLayout

Tags: nativescript

That works and the value of cnt is displayed:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="loaded">
    <Label text="{{ cnt }}" /> 
</Page>
```

That does not display the value of cnt:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="loaded">
    <StackLayout>
      <Label text="{{ cnt }}" /> 
    </StackLayout>    
</Page>
```

The model is:

```
var observable = require("data/observable");
var upDownViewModel = new observable.Observable({cnt: 0});

module.exports = upDownViewModel;
```

And loaded is:

```
exports.loaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = model;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Label needs a height to work with the StackLayout if a data binding is used.